# protratcor : Issue with using executescript to execute javascript on an element

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, protractor

I have written below code to execute `javascript` on an element. The code is as below:

```
 this.executeScript = function(locatorType, locatorValue, script){
        var element = this.getElement(locatorType, locatorValue);
        try{
            browser.executeScript(script, element);
        }
        catch(e){
        }
    };
```

I am calling this from a function in page script as below:

```
this.clickLoginButton = function(){     elementController.executeScript(commonFunction.getValueFromJson(elementLandingPage,'landingPage.loginButton.locator'),
            commonFunction.getValueFromJson(elementLandingPage,'landingPage.loginButton.value'),"arguments[0].click();");
    };
```

On executing the test script using `protractor` nothing happens on web page. Other functions like entering username and password are also not working. While clicking on element using direct click API of `webdriver` is working fie for me. This issue only occurs when I try to execute `javascript`.

Following error is shown on command prompt after long wait:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

  220607 ms: Mark-sweep 1387.6 (1435.4) -> 1385.7 (1435.4) MB, 27.7 / 0 ms [all
cation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  220637 ms: Mark-sweep 1385.7 (1435.4) -> 1385.7 (1435.4) MB, 31.0 / 0 ms [all
cation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  220667 ms: Mark-sweep 1385.7 (1435.4) -> 1385.7 (1435.4) MB, 28.6 / 0 ms [las
 resort gc].
  220688 ms: Mark-sweep 1385.7 (1435.4) -> 1385.7 (1435.4) MB, 27.2 / 0 ms [las
 resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 000000C4BBFB4639 <JS Object>
    1: wrapCallSite(aka wrapCallSite) [C:\Users\abhinav.s\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
de_modules\protractor\node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:~30
] [pc=0000025812D46013] (this=000000C4BBF041B9 <undefined>,frame=00000260792131
1 <a CallSite with map 000002B62D3ACC21>)
    2: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [C:\Users\abhinav.s\AppData\Roaming
npm\node_modules\protractor\node_...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

Can someone let me know solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

Changing `browser.executeScript(script, element);` to `browser.executeScript(script, element.getWebElement());` solved the problem.

Correct code is as below:

```
this.executeScript = function(locatorType, locatorValue, script){
        var element = this.getElement(locatorType, locatorValue);
        try{
            browser.executeScript(script, element.getWebElement());
        }
        catch(e){
        }
};
```